# How to print when location changes realtime with Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using the mapbox default drop in UI provided in their SDK for iOS, and I call

```
let navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route,    locationManager: navigationLocationManager())
navigationViewController.delegate = self
present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This presents a navigation view controller, but when this is presented, I want to somehow print the current location of the user in realtime as he moves along the route. How do I do this without having to build my own custom navigation UI? Is it possible to do this using only the drop in UI?

Comment: What do you mean by "print the current location"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform lightweight actions in the [`-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:) delegate method, including printing the user's new location.